# SQL update statement to add one year to access_end date

Tags: php, sql, date

I can code in PHP but I'm not good with SQL at all. I need to run an update on a table in order to pass in a given user_id and set the "access_end" date for all products the user owns to one year from today's date.

Any help much appreciated

Database is MySQL

Table name is dap_users_products_jn

Relevant Fields in database are:

```
user_id | access_end_date | product_id

1       |   2012-10-26    | 34
1       |   2012-11-21    | 30
1       |   2012-12-22    | 3
2       |   2012-10-20    | 34
2       |   2012-07-18    | 30
2       |   2012-08-15    | 3
...etc
```

Comment: [`DATE_ADD(access_end_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) `WHERE user_id=...`, and look at the rest of the date / time functions you don't know yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update dap_users_products_jn
set access_end_date = date_add(now(), interval 1 year)
where user_id = 1
```

Comment: can also use `set access_end_date = now() + interval 1 year` rather than calling the function `date_add()`. It may improve performance though I have not tested

Comment: I'd recommend using curdate() instead of now() if you don't want the time component added to the resulting date.

Comment: Sweet. Figured it would be simple. Thanks and +1